# How to access cached articles in newspaper3k

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-newspaper

Newspaper is a fantastic library that allows scraping web data however I am a little confused with article caching. It caches the article to speed up operations but how do I access those articles?

I have something like this. Now when I run this command twice with the same set of articles, I get the return type `None` the second time. How do I access those previously cached articles for processing?

`newspaper_articles = [Article(url) for url in links]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this: https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/issues/481 it seems the caching method 'cache_disk' in https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/blob/master/newspaper/utils.py may have a bug. It indeed does cache the results to disk (search for a folder '.newspaper_scraper'), but doesn't load them afterwards.

A workaround is to set memoize_articles=False when building your newspaper, or using the Config class.

```
newspaper.build(url, memoize_articles=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

After check from source code, It depends.

https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/blob/beacce0e167349374ce0b37012b01c7c07a26890/newspaper/settings.py#L35

```
DATA_DIRECTORY = '.newspaper_scraper'

TOP_DIRECTORY = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), DATA_DIRECTORY)
```

so run this in your python interpreter to get locations of cache

```
import tempfile
tempfile.gettempdir()
```